# Generation of Visual Studio Ultimate UML Class diagram from custom model

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uml, modeling

i've got quite the task at hand. I'm currently working in a long term project which has been running for 10 years. The domain classes are generated from a custom model stored in a database with a lot of customization and adaption for the project.

Now we want to use this existing model and transform / export / generate a Visual Studio Ultimate (2010/2012) class diagram. My favorite way would be to reference some library, fill up some classes, call some "WritItToThisFile" method and be happy ever after ;)

I did a little bit of searching, but i can only find the well known links to the Microsoft Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK Samples and Documentation which seems not quite so helpful for the task at hand, because i do not want to define a new Domain Specific Language but to use the existing Microsoft stuff.

Has anyone any idea or had a similar task and solved this?

Comment: This sounds super broad... I'd suggest a day (a few of your evenings) bashing Google. I say this only because your account is fresh (I'm no uber guru), but StackOverflow wroks the best when you have specific questions! Not that this isn't a good one mind you, it's just that's when it works best :) . Happy coding yourself!